# zero label in the values ​I predicted (y_prediction)

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I had 3 classes and I tagged 1,2,3 while tagging with csv file. When I try the model by separating 70 by 30 trains and tests, the accuracy value gives good results. However, while drawing the confusion matrix, it looks like 4 classes and a zero class emerges. Why does this happen how can I fix it.

For example:

```
print(testY[0:100])
print(y_prediction[0:100])
```

[2. 1. 3. 2. 2. 3. 1. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 3. 1. 3. 2. 3. 2. 3. 1. 2. 1. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 1. 2. 1. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 1. 2. 3. 3. 3. 1. 2. 1. 2. 2. 3. 1. 1. 1. 3. 3. 2. 1. 3. 3. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 3. 3. 1. 3. 2. 1. 3. 3. 1. 1. 1. 2. 3. 2. 1. 1. 2. 1. 1. 3. 3. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1. 1. 2. 2. 1. 3. 3. 3.]
[0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 2]

Why does this happen how can I fix it.

Comment: Class indices always start from 0, not from 1.

Comment: When I label 0, 1 and 2, the accuracy is 98%, while the confusion is very low, which may be the reason?